# Is there any good explanation for samples softmax and NCE loss other than in tensorflow candidate sampling tutorial ?

Tags: tensorflow

I went through this description on candidate sampling notes by tensorflow API. [Here is the link to the tf tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/candidate_sampling.pdf). But it's not much clear. Specially when talking about how they work with sample selecting.

Comment: In the tutorial of sampled softmax I don't understand the flow. Where it's try  to maximize the true class probability out of given C sampled classes. Specially how they select that C sampled classes.

Comment: It's based on the concept of `importance sampling`, a technique about how to efficiently generate samples from distributions when the distributions are multi-modal or very complex. This is done with the help of a proposal distribution `Q(x)` from which it is easy to draw samples from, say a Gaussian. Maybe reading about that would help

Comment: can you explain me following probability distribution ? 
P(t1=y |x, c) 
Here this is probability of the correct class given context and sampled class distribution ?